# Выбрать несколько параметров

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

Как я могу выбрать несколько параметров при создании конструктора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Стрелка Вниз</kbd> — выбрать первые несколько параметров
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd> — добавить/убрать один конкретный параметр
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> — выбрать все параметры